# How to denote Hermitian off-diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} x+w & f^*+w \\ f+w & x+w\end{pmatrix}$$

which I can write

$$x \mathbb{1} + w\mathbb{J} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & f^* \\ f & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

where $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity matrix and $\mathbb{J}$ is the matrix of ones. How can I write the last matrix in some compact form? $f^*$ is the complex conjugate of $f$ so I could write it

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & f^* \\ f & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ f & 0\end{pmatrix} + \mathrm{H.c.}$$

where H.c. is the hermitian conjugate, but I still wouldn't know how to write that first matrix in a conventional (or at least neat) form.

Comment: In the language of spins this might me rewritten as
$$\Re(f)\sigma_x+\Im( f) \sigma_y$$ where $\sigma_{x,y}$ are Pauli matrices

Comment: ooo I like this. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! as analternative for the whole expression:
$(x+\omega)\mathbb{1}+(\Re(f)+\omega)\sigma_x+\Im(f)\sigma_y$
which has the advantage that everything is written in terms  of ''basis-matrices'' of $\mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$